# How to stop results of nested stored procedure showing up at top level?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've made an alteration to an existing stored procedure (dbo.pr1) so that it now calls a second stored procedure (dbo.pr2).

Both of these stored procedures return data with a final SELECT query.

In dbo.pr1 I've now added the line:

```
EXEC @var1 = dbo.pr2
```

I've done this in order to assign the values in dbo.pr2 to the variable @var1 (dbo.pr2 returns a single bit).

However, now when I execute dbo.pr1 I get two results back instead of the expected one. I get the SELECT query results at the end of dbo.pr1 but I also get the SELECT query result from dbo.pr2.

I cannot alter dbo.pr2 as it's being used elsewhere in the system. Is there a way that I can stop its result showing up when I execute dbo.pr1?

Comment: I'm sure there is - can you show the stored procedures?

Comment: If you don't already, trying putting this in pr2: SET NOCOUNT ON;

Comment: Another suggestion, if the purpose of these sprocs are only to return a table of data then change them into table value functions.

Comment: The syntax: `EXEC @var1 = dbo.pr2` will only receive the value of a `RETURN` statement executed in the called procedure, and only if it is an integer.  To return the results of a `SELECT`, you would need to use the `INSERT ... EXEC ...` syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do something with what is returned in the caller,

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

...


DECLARE @resultsOfPr2 TABLE
(
    ...
);

INSERT @resultsOfPr2
EXEC @var1 = [dbo].[pr2];
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/592cc/2)

---

**Note:** I'm assuming `[dbo].[pr2]` selects a single result set.

Comment: Yes it does. Are you creating a table there? It's confusing the way you have it commented out.

Comment: Wanted to write this exact answer, prepared a SQLFiddle to demonstrate it, posting it here to help out with the answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/592cc